# How to remove horizontal borders from QHeaderView

Tags: qt, qtableview, qheaderview, qframe, qabstractitemview

I Have QTableView object with horizontal headerView, (vertical I have hidden).
I set setShowGrid(false) to remove grid from qtableView, but how can I remove separator borders between QTableView and its horizontal header.
I tried:

```
tableView->horizontalHeader()->setFrameShape(QFrame::VLine)
```

but without success.
thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK I reimplemented paintSection method and now I have what I wanted/

```
void MyHeaderView::paintSection(QPainter *painter, const QRect &rect,  int logicalIndex) const
{
  QString data = model() -> headerData(logicalIndex, orientation(), Qt::DisplayRole).toString();

  QFontMetrics fm = painter -> fontMetrics();

  painter -> fillRect(rect, QBrush(QColor("white")));
  painter -> drawText(rect, Qt::AlignLeft, data);

  painter -> drawLine(rect.topRight(), rect.bottomRight());
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you mean the same "border" as I do, it's a part of the current style. So, if you want to get rid of it, you have to define your custom style using the ***style sheets***.

Here is an example:

```
QString style = R"( QHeaderView::section {
                        border: 1px solid black;
                        border-bottom: 0px;             
                    }
                  )";

tableView->horizontalHeader()->setStyleSheet(style);
```

This style sheet sets an overall border of your header section to the 1px width black line and hides the bottom border.

Note: I am using a *C++11 raw string literal* here, so don't get confused. It's just a string.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, But there is one problem, I cannot use setStyleSheet() method, don't you know how to do the same with c++ commands, without css?

Comment: A am afraid there is no method in the Qt API to switch the bottom border of the header off. If you can't use the style sheets there is another option: Reimplement the QHeaderView::paintSection() method.